# Has JPA replaced CMP?

Tags: java, jpa

No question too stupid right :)

Came across this on wikipedia

> The Java Persistence API replaces the persistence solution of EJB 2.0
>   CMP (Container Managed Persistence).

My understanding was the CMP is still there i.e Pooling,Transactions etc can be done via CMP where as JPA is ORM for me. I did not think there are even same thing . I thought may be CMP VS JTA might make sense but obviously not.
I know how off track I am but thats why I am here may some can help me get things in perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMP is still there in that an app using CMP and entity beans will still work on a Java EE 6 server, but they are considered deprecated. So the statement you cited is true: CMP is being replaced by JPA.

> My understanding was the CMP is still there i.e Pooling,Transactions etc can be done via CMP

Neither connection pools nor transactions have anything to do with CMP. In fact, there is a completely separate expression for the latter: Container Managed Transactions (vs. Bean Managed Transactions).

CMP never was anything but a kind of overengineered and underperforming ORM.